# Pattern for address field in android Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using regex pattern for address field which must accept both (alphanumeric and /.-,) But in my code I did some mistake and it doesn't match regex properly can any body tell the issue, why it is not working properly?

matches only a single character,i want to match it on whole address text.

Here's example:

```
public static boolean Address(EditText etAddress, String sAddress) {

    Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Z.,-/ ]");    
    Matcher ms = ps.matcher(etAddress.getText().toString());    
    boolean bs = ms.matches();
    if (bs == false) {    
        etAddress.setError("error");
        bs = true;

    } else {
        etAddress.setError(null);
        bs = false;
    }
    return bs;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i made some changes to your code according to your needed solution:

```
public static boolean Address(EditText etAddress, String sAddress) {
    //changed your pattern text according to your requirements
    Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("[-0-9A-Za-z.,/ ]+");    
    Matcher ms = ps.matcher(etAddress.getText().toString());    
    boolean bs = ms.matches();
    if (bs == false) {    
        etAddress.setError("error");
        bs = true;

    } else {
        etAddress.setError(null);
        bs = false;
    }
    return bs;
}
```

this will work now perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

`[0-9A-Z.,-/ ]` matches only a single characters.

Append `+` to match multiple (1 or more) characters:

```
[0-9A-Z.,-/ ]+
```

`[A-Z]` matches only uppercase alphabet. To also match lowercase alphabet add `a-z`. Put `-` at the beginning or at the end of the character set. Otherwise, it could lead to a mistake (instead of matching  `-` literally, used as meta-character meaning range).

```
[-0-9A-Za-z.,/ ]+
```